# Postgres remote connection

Tags: postgresql

I'm having trouble getting postgres to allow remote access over the LAN. The 2 conf files are as follows...

```
#postrges.conf

# - Connection Settings - .200 is where the server's IP
listen_addresses = '192.168.0.200,localhost'
port = 5432
...

#pg_hba.conf
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# allow LAN connections only...
host    all             all             192.168.0.0/255         md5
```

Whats wrong here? The postgres server won't even restart...

Answer (score 2):

```
 # allow LAN connections only...
 host    all             all             192.168.0.0/255         md5
```

try to change that into CIDR notation

```
 # allow LAN connections only...
 host    all             all             192.168.0.0/32         md5
```

try to change

```
listen_addresses = '192.168.0.200,localhost'
```

into

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

About the not restarting: check your postgres logfile or on liux: /var/log/syslog

If the postgres server is restarting, check if its running on the needed interfaces using

```
  netstat -tapn
```

Comment: +1 - Host lists in pg_hba.conf are CIDR masks.  /255 **IS NOT** a valid CIDR mask (even IPv6 only understands up to /128).  Consult the man page for more information.

Comment: /255 is Very Wrong, but /32 is also probably not right.  I suspect that Jake is trying for /24

Comment: agreed, /32 should be /24 ... my mistake.